# How to Integrate non ASP.NET application as a Relying party in Azure ACS?

Tags: azure, acs

We have a web application hosted on Linux platform using Apache and PHP. We would like to configure this application as a relying party in Azure ACS. All the examples I see show how to do this for an ASP.NET application. Is it possible to make a non ASP.NET as a relying party in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can setup your PHP web application as a relying party but you will need to leverage a claims-aware security provider like SimpleSamlPhp (https://simplesamlphp.org/).